# Get all permutations of substrings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get all permutations possible from a list of substrings,

Let's take `['ab', 'CD', '12']` as input list.

I want:

```
'ab', 'CD', '12', 'abCD', 'ab12', 'CD12', '12ab', '12CD', ..., 'abCD12', 'CDab12', '12abCD'
```

Because input list will be dynamical, I need a pythonic solution, probably using `itertools` over nested `for`.

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: @nicomp I've googled for this quite a lot, i've also tried my hand with itertools.products and itertools.permutations, I can perform a character based permutation, i can't manage to get a substring based permutation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from itertools import permutations

input_list = ['ab', 'CD', '12']
output_list = []

for r in range(len(input_list)+1):  # Start at 1 if you don't want empty permutation
    for p in permutations(input_list, r):
        output_list.append(''.join(p))

print(output_list)
```

Comment: Please don't do people's homework for them.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. How do I improve my answer?